# Opening a new layout from a different layout?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I followed this tutorial (It's old, but I couldn't find any others; http://learnandroid.blogspot.com/2008/01/opening-new-screen-in-android.html)

So, I have it so that when I click on some text, it should open a different layout.

This is the XML code for the text I click on to open it:

```
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Not a member? Sign up now!" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/signupText" 
android:layout_gravity="center"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the Java coding for the Layout with the clickable text on it (The first "screen"):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NetworkActivity extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
   {
      super.onCreate(icicle);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      TextView click = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signupText);
      click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View arg0) {
          Intent i = new Intent(NetworkActivity.this, Signup.class);
          startActivity(i);
          } 
       });
    }
 }
```

The Java code for the second layout:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Signup extends Activity
{
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
  super.onCreate(icicle);
  setContentView(R.layout.signup);
  TextView b = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signupText);
  b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View arg0) {
     setResult(RESULT_OK);
     finish();
     } 
  });
 }
}
```

There's nothing special in the XML code for the second layout. (Should there be?)

When I click on the text in the Emulator, I get the error message that it's closed unexpectedly. How do I fix this?

Oh, and I saw other questions kind of like mine, but they weren't any help. I'm new to all this, so please don't get angry if I've done something "wrong". Thanks for the help in advance. =]

Comment: Please post the output of `logcat`, there's a stacktrace in there detailing the cause of Android force-closing your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you didn't register your second activity in your android manifest. You need to create a `<activity>` tag for each one in your app. There should be an error in the logcat, basically saying *"Could not find activity (Have you declared it in your manifest?)"*.

All you have to do to fix this, is add the tag inside your `<application>` tag:

```
<activity android:name=".Signup" android:label="@string/title_of_the_activity" />
```

See the [`<activity>` tag documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) for further information.

Comment: I only have the Hello string and the app_name strings. Should I have another?

Comment: You can create a new one if you like. `title_of_the_activity` was just an example. Either use `app_name`, `hello` or anything else. It's just the title that gets displayed at the top.

Comment: Ok, I have that in there, but it's still doing it. :(

Comment: Then check the logcat and see what the error/stacktrace is (should be printed in red). Also post it here so we can help you further. You can open the logcat in eclipse, go to `Window -> Show View -> Other -> Logcat` or by launching the ddms app from the `ANDROID_SDK/tools` folder.

Comment: It says "Invalid page preference path - XML Syntax".

Comment: That was the Error log, sorry. The Logcat doesn't say anything actually.

Comment: Mh you sure? You get the "Application stopped unexpectly?" dialog? In this case, theres almost a 100% chance you got a log error. Try creating a log filter via the small + and use the tag `AndroidRuntime`. Maybe you just missed it.

Comment: Yeah, I created a filter and it still doesn't show anything. I still get the error in the Emulator though.

Comment: My Logcat has a ton of errors and warnings in it, too many to post here.

Answer (score 1):

thy with this method it worked for me (here use button)

```
    View.OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener(){



        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {

                case R.id.button1: 
                      setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
                      break;
                case R.id.button2: 

                    setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
                    break;
                case R.id.button3: 

                     setContentView(R.layout.layout3);
                     break;
                case R.id.button4: 

                    setContentView(R.layout.layout4);
                    break;

                  }
        }
   };
    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(handler);
    findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(handler);
    findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(handler);
    findViewById(R.id.button4).setOnClickListener(handler);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can do this by simply specifing
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="name_of_method"
in xml file of TextView.